Why does WSL recognize the host as <PC_NAME>.mshome.net?
I was having trouble connecting to my Ubuntu OS running in WSL2
But then when I changed the bind-address of the config file at /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.
Then on the Windows host I was getting a new error:
Access denied for user mysqluser@DESKTOP-JS3KMNG.mshome.net

I then created a new MySQL user inside the Ubuntu on WSL using the following credentials:
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'DESKTOP-JS3KMNG.mshome.net' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

And then it worked, I was able to connect to the Ubuntu's MySQL server from the Windows host (I was using MySQL Workbench if that matters)
Where did the mshome.net come from, and, is there a more convenient way to connect to the WSL other than using this credential <PC_NAME>.mshome.net?

Is just using the IP address of the WSL instance more convenient?

I mean actually the <PC_NAME>.mshome.net is probably better because it's static as opposed to the WSL instance IP which can change, however I was not expecting that, and not sure where did it come from because I remember in the past I was using the instance IP so I was surprised that they are using an actual domain. But I didn't encounter that in the docs. Is it even written in the docs that <PC_NAME>.mshome.net is how the WSL instance sees the host?

The .mshome.net suffix is part of the windows internet connection sharing (ICS) service, which is tied into wsl. For example, in WSL2 (at least with hyper-v enabled), hostname.local points to win host's wsl adapter in wsl, while hostname.mshome.net points to win host's default switch of hyper V adapter in wsl

it’s not new
